# Using np.piecewise to have segmented linear regression to large data set

Tags: python, linear-regression, data-analysis, data-fitting, piecewise

For my data analysis I wish to get linear fits for different segments of the data. Since its a large data set I want python to calculate the lineair fits and the corresponding segments. I think the best way of doing this is by using np.piecewise, but in problem solutions they already know how many linear fits or what the segments are. Does anyone have a nice way of doing this?

Cheers

Comment: I don't have a nice general way. Some examples of linear piecewise fittings are shown in : https://fr.scribd.com/document/380941024/Regression-par-morceaux-Piecewise-Regression-pdf

Comment: Thanks, is there also an english version? And can you maybe have a look at my other question, because I keep getting this error? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63814704/keep-getting-this-error-using-numpy-piecewise-to-get-segmented-linear-regression

Comment: As far as I know no English translation of the referenced paper is published. About your previous question, sorry I cannot help. I am not familar with the software language used in your code.